# How do I plot the percentage of X per Y from the total number of X per category Z

Tags: r, statistics

Let's say I want to visualize how my hypothetical students are doing with respect to their majors. I have 32 students in my class Data Frames 101. What I'm interested in doing is plotting the percent of students per major per grade decile.

Here's my sample data frame.

```
# Grade Decile
grade <- c(90, 90, 90, 80, 80, 80, 80, 70, 70, 60, 50, 50)
# Student Major
major <- c("history", "math", "science", "history", "science", "english", "math", "english", "math", "english", "math", "history")
# Number of students per major per decile
num <- c(3, 6, 2, 3, 5, 2, 4, 5, 5, 2, 1, 1)

df <- data.frame(grade, major, num)
```

Then I extract only the English majors.

```
df_english <- df[df$major == "english",]
```

How do I plot the **percentage** of English majors from the total number of majors of the students who scored a certain grade?

Ultimately what I'm trying to show (with this hypothetical data set) is how many students who scored a certain grade chose a certain major, but controlling for the unevenness in the number of students in a majors.

I tried plotting df_english$num against df_english$grade divided by nrow(df$grade), but I think I'm way off base here. I also tried adding a new column again using nrow(df$grade), but no dice.

Any advice, criticism, pseudo-code, direction, or actual code is welcome. Base R or something from the tidyverse is equally welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ideas using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

df %>%
  complete(major, grade, fill = list(num = 0)) %>%
  group_by(major) %>%
  mutate(sum = sum(num),
         perc = num/sum) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = major, y = perc, fill = as.factor(grade), group = as.factor(grade))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge2(width = 0.5, preserve = "single"), width = .5) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

**Plot**

[image: percent vs. major by grade level]

And alternatively,

```
df %>%
  group_by(grade) %>%
  mutate(sum = sum(num),
         perc = num/sum) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = grade, y = perc, fill = major, group = major)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9, preserve = "single")) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

**Plot**

[image: percent vs grade by major]

You can stack the bars as well to 100% as an option. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer! This definitely helps a lot. Unfortunately, something I didn't really represent in the sample code, I have 50 "majors" and 50 "grades" which are continuous (so really have to have only "english" for example. I can follow the logic though so I think I can tweak it a bit to accomplish what I need. Thanks again for the direction!

Answer (score 1):

Using `tapply` you could summarize the numbers per grade and major. Then just divide number of english majors by the sum of all to get the percentage, which then easily can be `barplot`ted. I'm using toy data with 50 majors and 50 grades.

```
tmp <- with(dat, t(tapply(num, list(grade, major), sum)))
calc <- tmp[rownames(tmp) == "EN"] / colSums(tmp)*100

b <- barplot(t(calc), ylim=c(0, 4.5), col="lightblue", xlab="Grade", ylab="Percent",
        main="Grades of english majors as percentage of all majors", xaxt="n", yaxt="n", border=FALSE)
box()
# x-axis
smj <- (1:50)[(1:50) %% 10 == 0]*.1
smn <- (1:50)*.1
axis(1, smj, at=b[seq(b) %% 10 == 0], tck=-.02, labels=F)
axis(1, smn, at=b, tck=-.01, labels=F)
mtext(formatC(smj, digits=1, format="f"), 1, 1, at=b[seq(b) %% 10 == 0])
# y-axis
axis(2, 1:50, at=1:50, labels=F)
mtext(paste(1:4, "%"), 2, 1, 0, at=1:4, las=2)
```

### Result

[image]

---

*Toy data*

```
set.seed(43)
dat <- expand.grid(grade=(1:50)*.1, major=c("EN", "LH", "DU", "BE", "ZX", "XM", "GG", "BV", "GN", "IW", 
"AT", "SM", "VH", "ND", "YC", "NA", "YN", "XH", "JT", "TD", "GS", 
"EY", "RQ", "NY", "GD", "BS", "WF", "GJ", "XO", "FV", "TQ", "MU", 
"FH", "LT", "GP", "ZY", "AZ", "GK", "EU", "XL", "VI", "JC", "CI", 
"UM", "QU", "JX", "EE", "XJ", "XX", "DM"),
                   stringsAsFactors=F)
dat$num <- sample(1:10, nrow(dat), replace=TRUE)
```

Comment: I tried using this with the data set I provided, but got this instead:
    > mtext(formatC(smj, digits=1, format="f"), 1, 1, at=b[seq(b) %% 10 == 0])    
    Error in mtext(formatC(smj, digits = 1, format = "f"), 1, 1, at = b[seq(b)%%10 ==  : 
  zero-length 'at' specified. Any idea?

Comment: @SleepyMiles You need to understand what each command does; specifically the `at=` option of the `mtext` function. Actually you can try to run just the `barplot` line without specifying the `xaxt="n", yaxt="n"` options; the remainder basically replaces the automated axis labeling.

Comment: Thanks, investigating now.